# Misuse of tags - <featured>

Tags: discussion

I just noticed today that some people have been [tagging their questions as `<featured>`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured).  In a few case, this is a legitimate mistake where they meant to use `<featured-image>` or `<featured-post>`.

It's easy enough to go through and re-tag questions, but it's a bit annoying to have to do this.  Is the "Featured" tab so misunderstood that people think they can throw their posts up there with a tag rather than a bounty?

I actually think it might be a good idea to ban use of `<featured>` as a tag altogether.  Opinions?

Comment: first I have ever heard of this; featured is of course moderator-only *and* meta-only ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@EAMann:**

I agree; the `<featured>` tag should be limited to people for whom StackExchange deems have the authority to use it.